# Prometheus query to average over time by a specific label

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, promql

I need to query a metric and find out the average value of the metric over a period of 24hrs. But using using `avg_over_time` directly on the metric won't work. There is a specific `ipaddr` label. The average has to be grouped by each `ipaddr`. Now, grouping is not allowed in `avg_over_time`. In such case, how can I find out the average of the metric over 24 hrs for each `ipaddr`?

The metric and its values are like this

```
K_utilization{ifName="Ds12:1/0/30",ipaddr="10.1.109.54",node="worker"}  3.5
K_utilization{ifName="Ds65:1/0/4",ipaddr="10.1.5.50",node="worker"} 13.2
K_utilization{ifName="Ds26:1/0/8",ipaddr="10.1.123.58",node="worker"}   3.2
K_utilization{ifName="Ds69:0/0/10",ipaddr="10.1.115.55",node="worker"}  6.2
K_utilization{ifName="Ds71:0/0/21",ipaddr="10.1.25.51",node="worker"}   13.5
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `avg_over_time` function expects a range vector, which means that you could (if I understood correctly) use subquery like:

```
avg_over_time(K_utilization[1h:5m])
```

This will look at the `K_utilization` metric for the last 1h at a 5m resolution, the result should contain all labels from the metric.

You could also aggregate the metric in the subquery by the `ipaddr` label with a `sum` subquery and then calculate the `avg_over_time`:

```
avg_over_time(sum by (ipaddr) (K_utilization)[1h:5m])
```

More info about [Prometheus subqueries](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#subquery)

Comment: The 2nd example seems to just results in `: parse error: unexpected \"(\""`

Comment: Which version of Prometheus are you using? If I'm not mistaken the subquery support was added in Prometheus 2.7 so you'll need at least that version. Running that query against an empty prometheus server (via docker) that doesn't contain the `K_utilization` metric yields an _Empty query result_ but not a parse error.

Comment: That might be it yeah, I'll verify our version and upgrade if needed.

Answer (score 3):

The following PromQL query returns the average `K_utilization` over the last 24 hours grouped by `ipaddr`:

```
sum(sum_over_time(K_utilization[24h])) by (ipaddr)
/
sum(count_over_time(K_utilization[24h])) by (ipaddr)
```

It uses [sum_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum_over_time) and [count_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count_over_time) functions for calculating the average value.

This query is roughly equivalent to the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT ipaddr, avg(value)
FROM K_utilization
WHERE timestamp > now() - interval '24 hours'
GROUP BY ipaddr
```

It is assumed that the `K_utilization` table contains the following fields:

```sql
ipaddr string
timestamp int
value float
```